# Get the range of start and end offset values without considering its immediate parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

I have two `span` elements inside of `p` tag. While selecting some text in that `p` I need to get the start and end offset of selected value using `window.getSelection()`.

My expectation is that while selecting the second `span` text like `'country'`, the start offset value would be `28` and end offset would be `34` without considering its immediate parent. However the actual value of start offset is `10` and end offset is `16`.

How can I meet my expected values?

```html
<p style="margin: 0px;">
  <span>Welcome to India which</span>
  <span>
    <span>was great country for tourist places</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

```js
private onKeyUp(event: any): void {
  let labelSelection = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.getSelection();
  let range: any = this.labelSelection.getRangeAt(0);
}
```

Comment: That is the offset in the node (a text node here).  I cannot understand where you come up with the numbers you quote as the expectation here, Please add more detail regarding that.

Comment: the expected values should come up without considering its immediate parent (span element) @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: So am i correct in thinking that you want the inner `span`s to be treated like one long string within a `<p>` - ignoring any nested nodes etc?

Comment: Absolutely yes @FrancisLeigh.

Comment: can i ask why is it that you have nested your text within spans?

Comment: @FrancisLeigh, I need to maintain the structure for my application.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a tricky problem, but was enjoyable to play around with.

Here's one day to do it:

Attach mouse event listeners to the containing element. Use `event.target` to identify the start and end nodes that were selected. Use these nodes to add offsets to the numbers reported by the raw selection.

Html:

```
<p id="outer" style="margin: 0px;">
  <span>Welcome to India which</span>
  <span>
    <span>was great country for tourist places</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
const flattenNodes = node =>
  Array.from(node.children).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.childElementCount > 0) {
      acc.push(flattenNodes(curr))
    } else {
      acc.push(curr)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])

const getOffsetForElementAtIndex = nodes => elementIndex =>
  nodes.reduce((sum, node, i) => (i < elementIndex ? sum + node.textContent.length : sum), 0)

const getSelection = ev => {
  const nodes = flattenNodes(ev.currentTarget).flat()
  const startElementIndex = nodes.indexOf(mouseDownElement)
  const endElementIndex = nodes.indexOf(ev.target)
  const { startOffset, endOffset } = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)

  const start = startOffset + getOffsetForElementAtIndex(nodes)(startElementIndex)
  const end = endOffset + getOffsetForElementAtIndex(nodes)(endElementIndex)
  console.log(`start: ${start}, end: ${end}`)
}
let mouseDownElement = null

const el = document.getElementById('outer')
el.addEventListener('mousedown', ev => (mouseDownElement = ev.target))
el.addEventListener('mouseup', ev => getSelection(ev))
```

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/eawjLd)